Unable to Update/Filter One Access Subform from another
I have a main form (frm_Update_Fleet_Data) with two embedded subforms (subfrm_Fleet_Data and subfrm_Ship_Details). subfrm_Fleet_Data contains the partial results of qry_Current_Fleet in a continuous form listing of ships in the fleet. Selecting any record in subfrm_Fleet_Data provides all the record data for the selected ship. That part of the form works perfectly. Where I'm having trouble is using a modal form (frm_Filters) to allow the user to create an ad hoc query. The user selects or enters field values which are then used to create a FILTER string ('strFilter'). I'm having difficulty passing the FILTER string to subfrm_Fleet_Details.Filter property.
[Main form with two subforms] (https://i.sstatic.net/BHMP1fcz.png)
[frm_Filters] (https://i.sstatic.net/pB8cRKZf.png)
I've tried storing strFilter in a text box on the main form, but I'm still not able to assign the string value to subfrm_Fleet_Details.Filter. Code for clicking on the Filter action button on frm_Filters as:
Private Sub cmd_RunFilter_Click()

Dim strFilter As String, intConds As Integer
intConds = 0
strFilter = ""

 (several blocks of code here to create strFilter)
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Filters"
    Forms!frm_Update_Fleet_Data.Form.SetFocus
    Me!Forms!subfrm_Fleet_Data.Filter = strFilter
    Me!Forms!subfrm_Fleet_Data.FilterOn = True
    
End Sub

When I execute the above block, I get an error at 'Me!Forms!subfrm_Fleet_Data.Filter = strFilter' saying "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist."
I have tried setting the focus on 'subfrm_Fleet_Data' before trying to set the Filter property but get the same error message.
